# How do I perform a partial search while preserving order using solr?

Tags: search, solr, solr4

Using Solr 4.0, I have a field Title_t(to store titles of books) which is of type TextField. Assuming that these are the following titles stored in my db:

- Physics Guide
- Tutorial on Theoretical Physics
- The General Physics
  Book

If one wants to search for a title "Physics Guide", then one could use 
Title_t:physics G*
this shows up all results

- Physics Guide
- Tutorial on Theoretical Physics
- The General Physics  Book

Now, to my question:

Why isnt the filter not showing only the "Physics Guide" result?
 Since the search criteria is "physics G*" and not "*physics G *", only one result should be displayed .Is there a way to preserve order in the search key word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing you query  `Title_t:physics G*` will become like

```
Title_t:physics df:G*
```

df here is default field(usually it will be text, check your config files). 
and default operator will OR. so it returns documents with Title_t having term 'physics' and documents with any fields copied default field with words starting with G.

Try with **ComplexPhraseQueryParser**

```
q={!complexphrase inOrder=true}Title_t:"physics G*"
```

Comment: `inOrder=true` preserves words order.